# rolling mean pandas on group by more than one columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

this is my dataframe analytics: glnumber,nom,Year, YerarMonth,nom,amount

```
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2018,201809,234294.31000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2018,201810,166337.95000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2018,201811,250590.67000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2018,201812,92206.82000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201901,196868.71000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201902,148145.20000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201903,110973.24000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201904,184858.18000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201905,119166.87000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201906,10428.10000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201907,19927.05000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201908,-22677.79000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2019,201909,-8560.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2020,202004,-26.25000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2020,202007,-0.02000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2021,202101,-105.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,,2021,202103,104.99000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2020,202007,9000.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2020,202008,14040.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2020,202010,31185.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2020,202011,14310.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2020,202012,11160.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2021,202101,14490.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient1,2021,202102,14670.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202003,21045.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202004,13340.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2C,2020,202006,15640.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202008,54165.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202010,51750.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202011,23000.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202012,19550.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2021,202101,21850.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2021,202102,23000.00000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient3,2020,202001,937.50000
4020 Honoraires de consultation,Aclient2,2020,202003,437.50000
```

I'm trying to do a rolling mean (3 last periods) for each glnumber, nom

```
analytics['mean'] = np.where((((analytics.glnumber.isnull()) | (analytics.glnumber.shift(1).isnull()) | (analytics.glnumber.shift(2).isnull()) |(analytics.glnumber.shift(3).isnull()) |
                               (analytics.glnumber == analytics.glnumber.shift(1) == analytics.glnumber.shift(2) == analytics.glnumber.shift(3))) &
                       ((analytics.nom.isnull()) | (analytics.nom.shift(1).isnull()) | (analytics.nom == analytics.nom.shift(1) == analytics.nom.shift(2) == analytics.nom.shift(3) ))), analytics.amount.rolling(3).mean(), 0)
```

I've this error
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution:
analytics.groupby(['glnumber','nom','Year'])['amount'].transform(lambda s: s.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())